# woocommerce add custom tooltip in order view

Tags: woocommerce

I'd like to add a tooltip like this in order status, on mouse over:
[image: tooltip example]

I tried to use `wc_help_tip` as follows:

```
$help_tip = 'Ti do un suggerimento: studia!';
                echo wc_help_tip(__($help_tip, 'mypluginname'));
```

As a result I get a similar behaviour: I display a question mark icon and on mouse over my custom text. I'd like to display my text in the same style as in WooCommerce order status column. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by myself using data-tip property as follows:

```
echo '<mark style="margin-bottom:2px;" class="order-status status-on-hold tips" data-tip="' . __('Document not created in MyPluginName', 'mypluginname') . '"><span>'. __('Not saved ', 'mypluginname') . '</span></mark><br />';
```